# Query Regarding the following proof $\text { Show that } I \leq S \leq I+100$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, solution-verification

My question:

> $$ \text { Let } S=\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{10000} \text { and } I=\int_{0}^{10000} \sqrt{x} d x . \text { Show that } I \leq S \leq I+100$$

Can you check my solution?

\begin{aligned}
&\text {  } \mathrm{I}=\int_{0}^{10000} \sqrt{x} d x=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x} d x+\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{x} d x+\cdots+\int_{9999}^{10000} \sqrt{x} d x\\
&\rightarrow \int_{0}^{1} 0 . d x+\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1} \mathrm{d} x+\ldots .+\int_{9999}^{10000} \sqrt{9999} d x \leq I \leq \int_{0}^{1} 1 . d x+\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{2} d x+\cdots+\int_{9999}^{10000} \sqrt{10000} \mathrm{dx}\\
&\rightarrow \sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\ldots . .+\sqrt{9999} \leq I \leq \sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\ldots . .+\sqrt{10000}\\
&\rightarrow \mathrm{I} \leq S\\
&\text { Also, } \mathrm{S} \leq I+\sqrt{10000}\\
&\therefore \mathrm{I} \leq S \leq I+100
\end{aligned}

Comment: There are some typos: sometimes you write $1000$ instead of $10000$. A part from this, the proof looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks good. If you are familiar with floor/ceiling functions, you can make your proof slightly neater by showing that:
$$
S - 100 = \int_0^{10000} \left\lfloor{\sqrt{x}}\right\rfloor \; \mathrm{d}x, \; S = \int_0^{10000} \left\lceil{\sqrt{x}}\right\rceil \; \mathrm{d}x
$$
Then:
$$
S - 100 = \int_0^{10000} \left\lfloor{\sqrt{x}}\right\rfloor \; \mathrm{d}x \leq \underbrace{\int_0^{10000} \sqrt{x} \; \mathrm{d}x}_{=I} \leq  \int_0^{10000} \left\lceil{\sqrt{x}}\right\rceil \; \mathrm{d}x = S
$$
which is the same as $I \leq S \leq I + 100$.